# Quick help in nginx conf

Tags: nginx

Can anyone help me with nginx "location" 
I want to add this block to my nginx conf

```
 location / {
       limit_conn zone_name 8; 
     }
```

I need to modify location  to /folder/index.php?file=x
Where x can be an string (e.g 7fe8j)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the problem. If you add that block to your nginx config, what doesn't work?

Comment: it works fine , but now i don't want location to be / .Rather i want location to be  /folder/index.php?file=x Where x can be an string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to modify `location` to `/folder/index.php?file=x` Where x can be
>   an string (e.g 7fe8j)

The short answer is you can't.

[`limit_conn`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLimitZoneModule#limit_conn) directive only works in `http`, `server`, `location` context. And [`location`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) directive only match against the URI (`/folder/index.php`) without query parameters (`?file=x`).

Comment: Ohh ......then it is possible to make it match /folder/index.php?file.The ?file is important for me as all file to be downloaded has this in their link.My objective is to control the max number of concurrent connections a downloader can make

Comment: `?file` can be match by using `if ($args ~ "^file=(.*)") {` but you'll get the `[emerg] "limit_conn" directive is not allowed here in` message if you put a `limit_conn` directive inside.

Comment: ohh.....any other way to limit connection for /folder/index.php?file=